# strange issue in kitchen InSinkErator power outlet

Tags: electrical, sink

I am trying to connect another very low power electrical equipment to the outlet that is used by the working InSinkErator... I tried connecting table lamp, fan etc to make sure .. it appears nothing other than InSinErator works off of that outlet. I am stumped. I know some electrical basics but cant think of how this can happen. Appreciate help

Comment: Did you flip the switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The receptacle is switched, as garbage disposals usually do not have an on/off switch themselves. Make sure the switch is on, providing power to the receptacle.

Comment: Your table lamp can then illuminate the area so you can find the reset switch on the bottom of your disposer after it overheats and shuts down from running continuously...